# How do I intercept deserialization in Kryo based on the super class?

Tags: java, kryo

I am using the following code to add hooks to Kryo deserialization.

```
private static class KryoWithHooks extends Kryo {
private static final class SerializerWithHook extends com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer {
  private final com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer old;
  private final Hook hook;

  private SerializerWithHook(com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer old, Hook hook) {
    this.old = old;
    this.hook = hook;
  }

  @Override
  public Object read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class type) {
    hook.preRead(type);
    return hook.postRead(old.read(kryo, input, type));
  }

  @Override
  public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, Object object) {
    // Add write hooks if needed.
    old.write(kryo, output, object);
  }
}

  public void addHook(Class<?> k, Hook h) {
    register(k, new SerializerWithHook(newDefaultSerializer(k), h));
  }
}
}
```

Then I add hooks after registering all the explicit classes.
So far so good.
The question is, how do I do the same if I don't know the class in advance, and only know the base class? I.e. I have

```
class Container {
  private Contained c;
}
```

Contained can have any number of subclasses, and I want to intercept its deserialization /before it is instantiated/. If I add the hook for Contained.class above, that doesn't get called (understandably), even though the hook for e.g. Container works fine.